# How to change a single property in trigger template of default TabItem?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, inheritance

What I want to achieve is easily explained: change the background color of a wpf-tabitem in case it is selected (it should fit the window background). All other properties of the default control should stay the same.

The dump solution I came up with is to copy the whole default style into my `ResourceDictionary` and replace the color `#FFF9F9F9` in the following section:

```
 <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected">
  /* ..... cutting some lines here ....*>
  <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="Bd">
   <Setter.Value>
    <SolidColorBrush>
    #FFF9F9F9</SolidColorBrush>
   </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
```

Obviously, I do not like this and tried to apply inheritance (`BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}"`). This had no effect. 
Then I experimented with template settings. However, I failed to deal with the border in the default template, referenced avobe by "Bd". Adding the border to my ContentTemplated worked, but all other funcionalities of the default TabItem were gone (mouseover etc).

Can someone give me a hint how to change this color property without copying the whole default template? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the color is not linked to a property (like `Background`) in the default template you will have to replace the template with an edited copy, there is no other (acceptable) way of changing it.

Comment: There is a property ("Panel.Background") but it is not accessible. I hoped there would be some workaround. Thank you for making it clear that there is no other way.